# Create new dataframe and new column at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wonder if we can create new DataFrame and new column at once as below.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Can I combine the 2 rows into 1
new_df = df
new_df['new column'] = new_df['col1'] * 2 + new_df['col2'] / 4

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: FWIW `new_df = df` does not create a new DataFrame. It will only create an alias for an existing one. If you want a separate instance you'll need to [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) it `new_df = df.copy()`

Comment: Why are you looking to combine those 2 statements? Even if you do combine them, you aren't saving a lot on this. It's better to have separate commands for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `.assign()` method of a data frame, creating a copy and adding a new column at the same time:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
>>> new_df = df.assign(col3=df["col1"] * 2 + df["col2"] / 4)
>>> new_df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3  2.75
1     2     4  5.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the code looks shorter, use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) right after creating a dataframe.
The code snippet can look like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).assign(new_column=lambda x: x['col1'] * 2 + x['col2'] / 4)
```